# how can i solve the problem on flutter (anroid studio)

Tags: flutter, dart

Because date_time_picker >=2.0.0 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and date_time_picker <2.0.0 depends on intl ^0.16.1, every version of date_time_picker requires intl ^0.16.1 or ^0.17.0.
And because every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.18.1, date_time_picker is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.
So, because pos_2 depends on both flutter_localizations from sdk and date_time_picker any, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because pos_2 depends on both flutter_localizations from sdk and date_time_picker any, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

what can i solve the error?

Comment: can you upload screenshot of flutter --version